# Bootstrap datepicker() is working fine but datetimepicker() is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I know this has been asked before but my problem is bit diff.
    My bootstrap `datepicker()` function is working fine. but `datetimepicker()` is not working in same file. Please figure out where I am doing wrong.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <!--Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timepicker.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorpicker.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datetimepicker.css" />

   </head>
  <body>

    <input type="text" class="form-control  datepicker" />


    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bs3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery_timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
          $(document).ready(function (e) {
               $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                  minDate: today
           }) 

        })
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

if I use `datepicker()` instead of `datetimepicker()` it will work fine.

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: or can you send the url of plugin which you are using ?

Comment: And please check for any error in console

Comment: it is showing error 
TypeError: jQuery(...).datetimepicker is not a function  in `console window`

Comment: @syed datetimepicker requires moment.js to be loaded first... Also in fiddle yo had included datepicker and not datetimepicker

Comment: Fiddle link does not work, anyway if you are using eonasdan datetimepicker see the [installing](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual) section in the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include `bootstrap-datetimepicker-3.css`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id').datetimepicker({
        format:'DD.MM.YYYY'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it is included.